# How to list array

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

I have an array that contains image file names like this

```
Array ( [0] => first.png [1] => second.png [2] => third.png [3] => anyone.png [4] => all.png [5] => usual.png )
```

I use foreach to make a list

```
foreach($use_img as $use_img_result){
$use_img1 .= '<img src="' . $use_img_result . '">' . "\n";
$use_img1 .= '<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n";
}
echo $use_img1


Result:
<img src="first.png">
<img scr="spacer.png">
   (loops thru entire array)
<img src="usual.png">
<img scr="spacer.png">
```

but what I need is a result without the last "spacer.png" like this:

```
<img src="first.png">
<img scr="spacer.png">
    (loop thru entire array)
<img src="usual.png">
```

Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: Modify `$use_img1` to eliminate the unwanted item, or use a `for()` loop to cycle through all but one of the array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster approach:

```php
// Use variable to hold use_img`s count
$size = count($use_img);
$images = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; ++$i) {
    $images .= '<img src="'.$use_img[$i].'">'.PHP_EOL;
    if ($i != ($size - 1)) {
        $images .= '<img src="spacer.png">'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo $images;
```

Comment: It should be `if ($i != $size-1)`. +1 for the fastest method though.

Comment: $images .= '<img src="spacer.png"'.PHP_EOL;
should be
  $images .= '<img src="spacer.png">'.PHP_EOL;

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way:

```
foreach($use_img as $use_img_result){
    $use_img1[] = '<img src="' . $use_img_result . '">' . "\n";
}
$use_img1 = implode('<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n", $use_img1);
echo $use_img1;
```

Or even better without the `foreach`:

```
$use_img1 =
'<img src="' . 
implode('">' . "\n" . '<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n" .'<img src="', $use_img)
. '">' . "\n";
```

Comment: both work - thanks. didnt think on using implode... the second one is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

We would just check if the array's current item is the last item or not. If not, we would add the spacer image.
Over here, the $i will keep track of the array's current index being iterated. And the `count` function will return the no. of elements in the array, which is 1 more than the last index number of the array itself. (As the array starts from 0, so for an array of size 5, the last index is 5-1 = 4).

```
foreach($use_img as $i=>$use_img_result)
{
     $use_img1 .= '<img src="' . $use_img_result . '">' . "\n";
     if (($i+1)<count($use_img)) $use_img1 .= '<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n";
}
echo $use_img1
```

Comment: the first code I wrote was like this but somehow didnt work... however, this does thanks.

Comment: @EdHanson select any of the answers to your question which you were satisfied with and worked fine, accept that answer. So as to give the person a morale boost :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition in your loop to don't add the spacer:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($use_img_result); $i++) {
   $use_img1 .= '<img src="' . $use_img_result . '">' . "\n";
   if ($i !== count($use_img_result)-1) {
       $use_img1 .= '<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n";
   }
}
echo $use_img1
```

Comment: this is the code I wrote and was trying to get to work before I posted the question. I have no idea why my code didnt work.. however, thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly count the array:

```
$nr = count($use_img);
```

Then set a var:

```
$i = 0;
```

Then if the last item in array is reached, filter the echo.
So, like this:

```
$nr = count($use_img);
$i = 0;
foreach($use_img as $use_img_result){
$use_img1 .= '<img src="' . $use_img_result . '">' . "\n";
if($i!=$nr) $use_img1 .= '<img scr="spacer.png">' . "\n";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: the second code I wrote whre I misplaced the $i++... however good example and nice description - thanks